# "in the corner of the mouth" or "at the corner of the mouth"?

Tags: prepositions

Tell me please which preposition I should use in the following context.

> Person A: What is that on your face?
>
> Person B: Where?
>
> Person A: Right **at**/**in** the corner of the mouth.

I tried to use Ngram to see which is corect, but results came up.

Comment: It depends; is the thing at least partially**in** the mouth  (but visible), or **at** (but not in) the mouth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***at, in, by, on, near*** (and probably other prepositions) are all "acceptable" in this context, but no single one is "correct". Don't sweat the small stuff. The average native speaker would be far more likely to wince at your use of ***the*** mouth (we'd almost always say ***your*** mouth here).

<sub>(Reposted from FumbleFingers comment)</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Although I think you can technically use "at" since the definition is:

> Expressing location [or arrival in a particular place or position]. [Def. from google dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB848GB848&ei=wsYlXdLPJeXsxgPFwLn4Dw&q=at+definition&oq=at+def&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i70i249j0l8j0i22i30.25158.27031..28987...2.0..0.95.423.6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i67j0i131i67j0i131j0i10.5oHM-WqipK8)

"In" gives more context and sounds better to my (BrE) ear.

> Expressing the situation of something that is or appears to be enclosed or surrounded by something else. (in this case, surrounded my the corner of their lips) [Def. from google dictionary](https://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB848GB848&ei=wsYlXdLPJeXsxgPFwLn4Dw&q=at+definition&oq=at+def&gs_l=psy-ab.3.0.0i70i249j0l8j0i22i30.25158.27031..28987...2.0..0.95.423.6......0....1..gws-wiz.......0i67j0i131i67j0i131j0i10.5oHM-WqipK8#dobs=in)